# .globals is not a valid Plugin property

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs

I want to integrate the QR code scanner feature in my react-native-based applications.

so I am installing the [react-native-vision-camera](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera) package.

According to documentation, I have to add `globals __scanQRCodes` inside `babel.config.js`

> globals: ['__scanQRCodes']

[image]

But after adding `globals __scanQRCodes` inside `babel.config.js`.
I got `BABEL TRANSFORM ERROR`
**.globals is not a valid Plugin property**

[image]

Answer (score 7):

we need to define the array as shown in the image below, you miss the square brackets like this:

```
plugins: [
  [
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin', 
    { globals: ['__scanQRCodes'] }
  ]
]
```

[see this image for proper understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKdFt.png)

Answer (score 0):

We need to do this 2 modifications:

```
  plugins: [
    [
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
      { globals: ['__scanCodes'] },
    ],
  ]
```

And finally:

```
npx react-native start --reset-cache
```